# fs.appendfile does not work when in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, append

I am trying to write a some content to each file in a directory. My idea is to read the directory and list all the files in the directory.

Then for each file append the location of the file in the text file as string.

For example: Directory contains 2 files, Sample2.content1.txt, Sample2.content2.txt.

I want to read the sample1.content1.txt and write its location within the file as location-c:\sample1.txt.

The format of the text in file is

```
Page 0 -/text.php
Page 1 -/60893.php
Page 2 -/1189.php
Page 3 -/20389.html
```

I am working on this but am stuck at why the append file does not write the content to file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/output',function(err,data)
{
     if(err) throw err;
     data.forEach(function(file){
         //console.log('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/output'+file)
         fs.appendFile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/output'+file,'appending this text to file','utf8',(err)=>{if(err) throw err; console.log('data was appended to '+file)})
    });
 });
```

Running this does not give me any error and console.log returns:
data was appended to sample2.content1.txt
data was appended to sample2.content2.txt

I wan to perform multiple actions on the file after the string is appended i.e parse the text in file and convert it to JSON format etc.

Hope you can help me.Am new to JS and Node.

Regards,
Jai

Comment: This is a generally bad practice because you are running multiple asynchronous operations in a loop and expecting them to be sequenced in the right order, but there is no guarantee they will go in the right order.

Comment: Any advice on how to approach this in a right waywill be great. I am new to the Node and JS and am just trying out.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake ...just found it...

I was looking in the wrong folder as the data was getting appended to the file as `outputsample2.content1.txt` because i missed a `'/' after output/`

so it should be

```
fs.appendFile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/output/'+file,'appending this text to file','utf8',(err)=>{if(err) throw err; console.log('data was appended to '+file)})
```

hope someone will find it useful.

Regards,
Jai